# Mongoose : Inserting JS object directly into db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

Ok so I have a JS object that is being POSTed via AJAX to the nodejs backend. I want to insert this js object directly into my mongoose db as the object keys already match up perfectly with the db schema.

**I currently have this (not dynamic and overly complex):**

```
app.post('/items/submit/new-item', function(req, res){
    var formContents = req.body.formContents,
        itemModel = db.model('item'),
        newitem = new itemModel();

    newitem.item_ID         = "";
    newitem.item_title      = formContents.item_title;
    newitem.item_abv        = formContents.item_abv;
    newitem.item_desc       = formContents.item_desc;
    newitem.item_est        = formContents.item_est;
    newitem.item_origin     = formContents.item_origin;
    newitem.item_rating     = formContents.item_rating;
    newitem.item_dateAdded  = Date.now();

    newitem.save(function(err){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        console.log('saved');
    })

    res.send('item saved');
});
```

**But want to trim it down to something like this (sexy and dynamic):**

```
app.post('/items/submit/new-item', function(req, res){
    var formContents = req.body.formContents,

    formContents.save(function(err){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        console.log('saved');
    })

    res.send('item saved');
});
```

Comment: *"Ok so I have a JS object that is being POSTed via AJAX to the nodejs backend. I want to insert this js object directly into my mongoose db as the object keys already match up perfectly with the db schema."* Sounds like an **excellent** vector for some kind of injection attack, similar to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always better to process and validate your data on the server before sending it. Clients cannot be trusted.

Comment: Yes I know. This is a test case. That was not my question.

Comment: So it's a bad test case, as you should ALWAYS validate data :) I'm currently working in a similar context and successfully tested validate.js to validate the data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a plugin like this with mongoose (http://tomblobaum.tumblr.com/post/10551728245/filter-strict-schema-plugin-for-mongoose-js) you can just put together an array in your form, like `newitem[item_title]` and `newitem[item_abv]` -- or `item[title]` and `item[abv]`

You could also just pass the whole `req.body` if the elements match up there. That *MongooseStrict plugin* will filter out any values not explicitly set in your schema, but it still leaves checking types and validation up to mongoose.  With proper validation methods set in your schema, you will be safe from any injection attacks.

**EDIT:** Assuming you have implemented the plugin, you should be able to use this code.

```
app.post('/items/submit/new-item', function(req, res){
  new itemModel(req.body.formContents).save(function (e) {
    res.send('item saved');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks the method you described worked without requiring the plugin. I will definately need to implement it at a further date to ensure security though. What is the point in schemas if they can be overridden like this? What other methods of input validation would you suggest?

Comment: Schemas do a lot in mongoose, most importantly they save types properly into mongodb but they also let you setup validation, defaults, and other ODM stuff.  At the moment the top level of a mongoose doc is essentially treated like the type "Mixed" (which accepts anything and only does stuff when the property updated matches a property in the schema) -- the plugin forces mongoose to *only* accept properties in the schema

Comment: Coming from a mySQL background I am struggling to understand mongoose fully. The docs are not that clear to me. Could you recommend some  resources or examples. I'm not looking to do anything advanced.

Comment: The google group is a good place to start, and you can usually find help on irc pretty quickly in #node.js on freenode.net

Comment: The schemas can contain validation code that is automatically executed -- i.e. **hidden** -- in your `save()` call.  That is the beauty of mongoose, in one line, you have validated your user input and saved it off to the DB.  You can also sanitize and change the input, by hooking into the model `.pre()` which can filter the user input for malicious input.  Your line of code will remain the same, but the schema automatically filters + validates...

Comment: @ThomasBlobaum, your link has rotted, do you have that plugin on github, or is it obsoleted by mongoose built-ins?

Comment: @NikMartin schemas are strict by default now

Comment: @ThomasBlobaum Thanks for that info, I'm just getting into mongoose as well.

Comment: @ThomasBlobaum do you mind if I edit your answer?  Finding outdated info on these sites drives me crazy when I'm searching. That's how I got to this answer, only to discover it's usurped.