# Cast JSON to Mongoose Schema to call Schema Method

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I've looked at this question ([Is there a native feature to convert string based JSON into Mongoose Schema object instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12048093/3688755)) and it's related to my question but doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for.

Essentially, I have JSON I've fetched from an Express response and I'd like to cast it to a Mongoose object for the purposes of calling a schema method on the object.

My schema looks something like this:

```
var BlahSchema = new Schema({
    folder: String,
    filename: String,
    original: String
});
...
// This is the function I wish to cal
BlahSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
    ...
});
```

From what I understand, when I have an object matching BlahSchema, I can call the method via a simple object.url.

I have two questions. First, the JSON I'm retrieving these objects from erases their schema, right? I'm retrieving these from the database via `Blah.search(...function(err, blahs))`. This all gets encoded into a JSON object which I return via `callback(req, res, search_result)` where search_result is an object created via `search_result.blahs = blahs`, etc. Is there any way to preserve this schema across calls? This would be the preferred method.

Second, if the above is not possible, how do I re-cast JSON to schema without using the save() function mentioned in the answer to the question I pose above? I don't want to re-add objects to the database; I just want to use a method defined for that schema.

EDIT: Express is pretty sick. All you have to do is blah(object).method_name, where blah = mongoose.model('blah')

Answer (score 3):

I save a User (Schema) object to redis in plain JSON.

Get the userData (string) and parse it to JSON object:

```
var user = new User(JSON.parse(userData))
```

... and you have all the methods of your User schema.

Comment: I think this works as well. Not sure if there's additional overhead based on 'new' or not though.

Comment: Why there would be any? It's just providing a new context (brand new object) to the executing function to be used in "this" calls.