# Convert JWT payload to Mongoose model instance

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, passport.js

I've set up the Local Strategy to include the user's `user instance` into a JWT payload, of course in JSON format, as follows:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  async function (email, password, done) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
      if (!user || !isCorrectPassword) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Email o contraseña incorrecto/s" })
      }

      return done(null, user.toJSON(), { message: "Ingreso existoso"})
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }
))
```

Now, when one of my routes calls `passport.authenticate()`, my JWT Strategy is configured to extract the user's id from the payload, **and then querying the DB in order to get back a mongoose model instance from that id**, to be stored in `req.user`. Like this:

```
passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
},
  async function(jwtPayload, done) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(jwtPayload._id)
      return done(null, user)
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }
))
```

I feel like querying the DB to get *the same* information that's encoded in the payload is super inefficient, so I'd like to do without `const user = await User.findById(jwtPayload._id)`, and return the payload instead (`return done(null, jwtPayload)`), but since `jwtPayload` actually JSON, and not a mongoose object, I fear it won't work out of the box.

How could I accomplish this? Is there a mongoose function that translates JSON to model instance?

Comment: Did you see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12079493/4515720)? I think it's about along the lines that you are asking

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find that when I searched... Should I delete this question?

Comment: Nah, you really shouldn’t delete questions unless they are low-quality. Someone might search this one day and find it!

Comment: I'm that someone. I have this exact question. Thanks for keeping it here.

Comment: Can you please add an answer if you found a solution? I'm stuck at a similar situation and the linked questions does have that answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: useful articles I found: [Johnny Situ](https://medium.com/@johnnysitu/node-js-user-authentication-with-passport-local-strategy-37605fd99715), [Toon.io](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow)

Comment: @Gangula see Evan Becthol's comment

Comment: the answere linked in that comment doesn't mention how to use jwt or passport. Can you help me understand how to use that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't used JS for years now, much less JWT... I hope you do find the answer!