# saving object instances in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, object, constructor, mongoose

I want to know if it's posible save an object created with constructor. Example:

i have an object constructor called Car.

```
function Car = function(color) {
  this.color = color;
}

Car.prototype.run = function(){/* code here */}

var carSchema = new Schema({
  ob: Schema.Types.Mixed
});

var model = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);

model.create({ob: new Car("blue")});

model.findOne({}, function (err, car) {
    if (err) { return; }
    if(!car) { return; }
    car.ob.run();  // it don't work
});
```

I could make something like this work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526639/mongoose-inserting-js-object-directly-into-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mixed schema type takes an object literal. But if you pass in an object literal with a function on it, it will be stripped out. I know. I have tried :).

There is a package that let's you store functions on a schema:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-function

This doesn't do exactly what you want since it doesn't let you store constructed objects.  It may give you an idea of what you'll need to do.  Basically, you are going to need to figure out a way to serialize your constructed object when you store it to Mongo and then deserialize after your retrieve it with the Mongoose search functions.

This wouldn't be terribly hard (see http://nanodeath.github.io/HydrateJS/) and you could write a custom schema field type like in the above mongoose-function package.

But all in all, it's a lot of work to get to where you are going. Why not just do the naive thing and store the state for your entities on the schema and use that in a regular instance method like so:

```
var carSchema = new Schema({
  color: Schema.Types.String
});

carSchema.methods.run = function  () {
   console.log(this.color);
};
```

However, I'm sure a lot of people might find a schema field type that did this very useful.